# Adding rows and removing rows to table using Jquery in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

**Here I have a table in Master Page**

table border="1" border-style="dashed" width="80%" id="tblAddBirthdays"
                        tr id="tr"
                td asp:TextBox ID="txFirstName" runat="server" asp:TextBox                asp:TextBox ID ="txLastName" runat="server" 
                asp:DropDownList ID="dlMonth" runat="server" 
                asp:DropDownList ID="dlDate" runat="server"
                asp:DropDownList ID="dlYear" runat="server"
                asp:DropDownList ID="dlAgeRange" runat="server"
                asp:DropDownList ID="dlRelationship" runat="server" 
                asp:DropDownList ID="dlGender" runat="server" 
**And Link Buttons**
            asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLess" runat="server" Text="(<<)Less "

OnClientClick="JavaScript: return false;" />  
        >)"  OnClientClick="jQuery:add()" />

**Now I want  to add rows to table by clicking on link button using Jquery Dynamically Asp.net Master Page , i am trying from two days not getting it , can any body help me..**

Answer (score 0):

Adding from the client side in ASP.NET may not work as expected because it will not update the viewstate of the ASP.NET webform . It will be better that you use the UpdatePanel and add the row. In normal jquery ADD use some thing like this

```
             var tbl = $("#tableId");
             tbl.appendTo('<tr><td></td></tr>');
```

You have to use the normal html fields like

```
            <input type="text" id="txt" name="txt" />
```